Problem with feature extraction for DRL agent on different input shapes
I am a novice graduate student who has just started learning reinforcement learning. Currently, I am following the OpenAI Gym framework to establish the interaction between my environment and agent, but I'm encountering problems with feature extraction for the agent.
Here are my thoughts:
The problem I'm dealing with is a scheduling problem. Currently, the state returned by the environment I designed has two parts: order_state and workstation_state, with shapes of (110,4) and (32,4) respectively. Since the shapes of my two states are different, I plan to separately use two CNN layers, flatten them, and then concatenate the two flattened one-dimensional arrays for my feature extraction.
However, my program is throwing an error. Here is the error:
  File d:\research\04-simulation model\em-plant\exp3\plantsim_rl3.py:269
    main()

  File d:\research\04-simulation model\em-plant\exp3\plantsim_rl3.py:255 in main
    agent.train(state, action, reward, next_state, done)

  File d:\research\04-simulation model\em-plant\exp3\plantsim_rl3.py:207 in train
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.q_network.trainable_variables)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\plantsim_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py:1113 in gradient
    flat_grad = imperative_grad.imperative_grad(

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\plantsim_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\imperative_grad.py:67 in imperative_grad
    return pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_TapeGradient(

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\plantsim_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py:160 in _gradient_function
    return grad_fn(mock_op, *out_grads)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\plantsim_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_grad.py:581 in _Conv2DGrad
    gen_nn_ops.conv2d_backprop_input(

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\plantsim_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py:1422 in conv2d_backprop_input
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\plantsim_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:7209 in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access

AbortedError: {{function_node __wrapped____MklNativeConv2DBackpropInput_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Operation received an exception:Status: 2, message: could not create a descriptor for a dilated convolution backward propagation primitive, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl/mkl_conv_grad_input_ops.cc:499 [Op:Conv2DBackpropInput]


2024-05-12 13:44:03.829841: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1780] OP_REQUIRES failed at mkl_conv_grad_input_ops.cc:502 : ABORTED: Operation received an exception:Status: 2, message: could not create a descriptor for a dilated convolution backward propagation primitive, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl/mkl_conv_grad_input_ops.cc:499

My code for main function, DQN agent & Q network
class QNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_actions):
        super(QNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')
        self.conv2 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')
        self.flatten = layers.Flatten()
        self.dense1 = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')
        self.output_layer = layers.Dense(num_actions, activation='linear')
    
    def min_max_normalize(self, tensor, min_val, max_val):
        tensor_min = tf.reduce_min(tensor, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        tensor_max = tf.reduce_max(tensor, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        return (tensor - tensor_min) / (tensor_max - tensor_min) * (max_val - min_val) + min_val

    def call(self, state):
        # normalize state
        # state_0_normalized = self.min_max_normalize(state[0], 0.0, 1.0)
        # state_1_normalized = self.min_max_normalize(state[1], 0.0, 1.0)

        # print(f"{np.shape(state_0_normalized)}\n{state_0_normalized}\n{np.shape(state_1_normalized)}\n{state_1_normalized}")
        # features_1 = self.extract_features(state_0_normalized)
        # features_2 = self.extract_features(state_1_normalized)
        
        state_0 = state[0]
        state_1 = state[1]
        features_1 = self.extract_features(state_0)
        features_2 = self.extract_features(state_1)
        # 將兩個特徵串聯在一起
        concatenated_features = tf.concat([features_1, features_2], axis=1)

        # 使用 Dense 層進行預測
        x = self.dense1(concatenated_features)
        return self.output_layer(x)

    def extract_features(self, arr):
        # 將陣列轉換為適合卷積層輸入的形狀 (batch_size, height, width, channels)
        arr = tf.expand_dims(arr, axis=0)
        arr = tf.expand_dims(arr, axis=-1)
        x = self.conv1(arr)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        return x

class DQNAgent:
    def __init__(self, num_actions, epsilon=1.0, epsilon_min=0.01, epsilon_decay=0.995, gamma=0.99, memory_size=10000):
        self.num_actions = num_actions
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.epsilon_min = epsilon_min
        self.epsilon_decay = epsilon_decay
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.q_network = QNetwork(num_actions)
        self.target_q_network = QNetwork(num_actions)
        self.target_q_network.set_weights(self.q_network.get_weights())
        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=memory_size)

    def select_action(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return np.random.randint(self.num_actions)
        else:
            q_values = self.q_network(state[None, :])
            return np.argmax(q_values[0])
        # return np.random.randint(self.num_actions) # completely random action

    def train(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        next_q_value = np.max(self.target_q_network(next_state)[0]) 
        target = reward + (1 - done) * self.gamma * next_q_value
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            q_values = self.q_network(state)
            action_mask = tf.one_hot(action, self.num_actions)
            q_action = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(q_values, action_mask), axis=1)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(target - q_action))
            tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss) 
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.q_network.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.q_network.trainable_variables))
        
    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))
    
    def replay(self, batch_size):
        if len(self.memory) < batch_size:
            return
        minibatch = np.random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
        for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
            target = reward
            if not done:
                next_q_value = np.max(self.target_q_network(next_state)[0])
                target = reward + self.gamma * next_q_value
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                q_values = self.q_network(state)
                action_mask = tf.one_hot(action, self.num_actions)
                q_action = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(q_values, action_mask), axis=1)
                loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(target - q_action))
            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.q_network.trainable_variables)
            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.q_network.trainable_variables))
        
    def update_target_network(self):
        self.target_q_network.set_weights(self.q_network.get_weights())
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay


tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs')

def main():
    # initialize environment
    env = Environment()
    # print(observation)
    
    # initialize DQN agent
    num_actions = env.action_space_n
    agent = DQNAgent(num_actions)
    
    # Train DQN agent
    for episode in range(1000):
        state = env.reset()
        total_reward = 0
        while True:
            # time.sleep(2)
            action = agent.select_action(state)
            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            agent.train(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
            agent.update_target_network()
            total_reward += reward
            state = next_state
            if done:
                break

        tf.summary.scalar('reward', total_reward, step=episode)
        
    print(f"Episode: {episode + 1}, Total Reward: {total_reward}")


# tensorboard --logdir=./logs
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

My state shape & matrix:
(110, 4)
[[1.000e+00 4.200e+01 4.200e+01 6.231e+04]
 [2.000e+00 1.300e+01 1.300e+01 1.290e+05]
 [3.000e+00 9.000e+00 5.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [4.000e+00 2.000e+01 2.000e+01 2.390e+05]
 [5.000e+00 1.800e+01 5.000e+00 5.655e+04]
 [6.000e+00 2.200e+01 2.200e+01 1.535e+05]
 [7.000e+00 1.500e+01 1.500e+01 9.418e+04]
 [8.000e+00 4.000e+00 1.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [9.000e+00 4.000e+00 4.000e+00 2.145e+05]
 [1.000e+01 2.100e+01 2.100e+01 2.146e+05]
 [1.100e+01 1.700e+01 1.700e+01 1.142e+05]
 [1.200e+01 2.700e+01 1.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.300e+01 4.000e+00 1.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.400e+01 3.300e+01 3.300e+01 1.584e+05]
 [1.500e+01 3.300e+01 3.300e+01 1.791e+05]
 [1.600e+01 7.000e+00 7.000e+00 8.486e+04]
 [1.700e+01 8.000e+00 7.000e+00 2.433e+05]
 [1.800e+01 1.900e+01 1.900e+01 1.379e+05]
 [1.900e+01 1.900e+01 1.900e+01 9.041e+04]
 [2.000e+01 2.600e+01 2.600e+01 1.784e+05]
 [2.100e+01 5.200e+01 5.200e+01 1.280e+05]
 [2.200e+01 1.600e+01 1.200e+01 2.345e+05]
 [2.300e+01 1.300e+01 7.000e+00 2.136e+05]
 [2.400e+01 2.600e+01 2.600e+01 2.331e+05]
 [2.500e+01 2.000e+01 2.000e+01 1.364e+05]
 [2.600e+01 2.600e+01 1.500e+01 0.000e+00]
 [2.700e+01 1.400e+01 4.000e+00 2.306e+05]
 [2.800e+01 1.800e+01 1.800e+01 1.406e+05]
 [2.900e+01 2.000e+01 2.000e+01 2.298e+05]
 [3.000e+01 1.300e+01 1.300e+01 1.797e+05]
 [3.100e+01 1.000e+01 3.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [3.200e+01 1.700e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [3.300e+01 2.200e+01 2.200e+01 1.975e+05]
 [3.400e+01 1.300e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [3.500e+01 2.000e+01 1.200e+01 1.635e+05]
 [3.600e+01 9.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [3.700e+01 2.200e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [3.800e+01 1.800e+01 1.800e+01 1.728e+05]
 [3.900e+01 1.500e+01 1.500e+01 1.667e+05]
 [4.000e+01 4.000e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [4.100e+01 1.700e+01 1.700e+01 1.861e+05]
 [4.200e+01 2.600e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [4.300e+01 2.200e+01 1.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [4.400e+01 9.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [4.500e+01 4.000e+00 4.000e+00 2.121e+05]
 [4.600e+01 2.000e+01 2.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [4.700e+01 7.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [4.800e+01 5.400e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [4.900e+01 2.600e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [5.000e+01 1.900e+01 1.900e+01 1.999e+05]
 [5.100e+01 3.900e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [5.200e+01 1.800e+01 1.400e+01 0.000e+00]
 [5.300e+01 2.000e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [5.400e+01 8.000e+00 2.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [5.500e+01 1.800e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [5.600e+01 2.000e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [5.700e+01 2.100e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [5.800e+01 9.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [5.900e+01 1.300e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [6.000e+01 4.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [6.100e+01 4.300e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [6.200e+01 2.000e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [6.300e+01 8.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [6.400e+01 8.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [6.500e+01 1.700e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [6.600e+01 1.700e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [6.700e+01 1.000e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [6.800e+01 2.100e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [6.900e+01 2.400e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [7.000e+01 8.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [7.100e+01 2.500e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [7.200e+01 2.100e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [7.300e+01 1.900e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [7.400e+01 2.400e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [7.500e+01 1.300e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [7.600e+01 2.600e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [7.700e+01 2.100e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [7.800e+01 2.600e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [7.900e+01 8.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [8.000e+01 8.000e+00 8.000e+00 5.488e+04]
 [8.100e+01 6.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [8.200e+01 2.600e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [8.300e+01 3.900e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [8.400e+01 2.200e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [8.500e+01 1.500e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [8.600e+01 9.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [8.700e+01 2.200e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [8.800e+01 1.800e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [8.900e+01 8.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [9.000e+01 2.600e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [9.100e+01 9.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [9.200e+01 8.000e+00 8.000e+00 1.396e+05]
 [9.300e+01 1.500e+01 1.500e+01 3.240e+04]
 [9.400e+01 3.300e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [9.500e+01 2.100e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [9.600e+01 2.100e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [9.700e+01 4.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [9.800e+01 8.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [9.900e+01 3.400e+01 3.400e+01 1.213e+05]
 [1.000e+02 1.800e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.010e+02 5.200e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.020e+02 4.200e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.030e+02 1.800e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.040e+02 1.600e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.050e+02 2.700e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.060e+02 9.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.070e+02 2.100e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.080e+02 5.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.090e+02 9.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.100e+02 2.500e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]]
(32, 4)
[[ 1.  3.  3.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 1.  5.  5.  0.]
 [ 1.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 2. 20. 20.  0.]
 [ 2. 10. 10.  0.]
 [ 2. 10. 10.  0.]
 [ 2.  5.  0.  0.]
 [ 2. 15.  4.  0.]
 [ 2. 20.  0.  0.]
 [ 2. 10.  0.  0.]
 [ 2. 15.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  5.  0.  0.]
 [ 2. 10. 10.  0.]
 [ 3.  2.  1.  0.]
 [ 3.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 3.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 3.  3.  2.  0.]
 [ 3.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 3.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 3.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 3.  2.  1.  0.]
 [ 3.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 3.  3.  2.  0.]
 [ 3.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 3.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 3.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 3.  1.  1.  0.]]

Is there any problem with my code?
